# To display a message on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML markup like this, When,

```
<span class="placesBostPageHelpBg  placesBostHelpBg floatLeft voteHelpToolTip" id="HelpToolTipButton2">
<span class="placesBostHelpText">?</span>
</span>
```

CSS Used for Wrapper Span is

```
.placesBostPageHelpBg {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #171716;
color:#63E6F4;
cursor:pointer;
height:20px;
left:5px;
position:relative;
top:-2px;
width:20px;
z-index:1;
-moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Css used for Question mark

```
.placesBostHelpText {
left:6px;
position:absolute;
top:2px;
z-index:2;
}
```

The output is just like a circle and inside the circle there is question mark. When anyuser click on that circle i have to display a message. Its working fine.
But My Question is when i click on circle  the circle it display a message but when i click on question mark the message would not display.

Used Java Script

```
$('#HelpToolTipButton2').click(function() {$('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').toggle();});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#HelpToolTipButton2').click(function() {$('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').toggle();});
```

Since span is a child element of the circle element click on that span will cause event bubbling. To prevent this put `return false;` at the end of the click function.

```
$("span.placesBostHelpText").click(function(){
     $('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').hide();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Only u need to change $("span.placesBostHelpText").click(function(){
     $('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').toggle();
     return false;
}); No need to hide this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fire click event on both span....something like

```
  
$('.placesBostHelpText #HelpToolTipButton2').click(function() {$('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').toggle();});
```

Answer (score 0):

u have html markup

```
<span class="placesBostHelpText">?</span>
```

u can't show message if u write script like this

```
$('#HelpToolTipButton2').click(function() {$('#voteHelpMessageContainer2').toggle();});
```

my opinion is u can use this script :

```
$('.placesBostHelpText').click( function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

i think u have idea to join / change it in your script